# When redirecting printf to UART, output lines have a stair-stepped appearance

Tags: c, embedded, printf, stm32, uart

I am just starting with STM32 microcontrollers, and I am redirecting the output of `printf` to UART. For some strange reason, the displayed terminal keeps adding extra spaces that are not present in the code. I can't seem to find the cause for this.

Here is a screenshot of the displayed output; note the stair-stepped appearance as each `printf` statement is wrapped to a new line that is more deeply indented than the previous one:

[image: Displayed output from UART in a terminal window.]

Here is the code that I am using for redirecting `printf`:

```c
int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
{
    HAL_USART_Transmit(&husart3, (uint8_t*)ptr, len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    return len;
}
```

I am invoking this code as follows:

```c
printf("program starting...\n");
int counter = 0;
while(1)
{
    printf("counter = %d\n", counter);
    counter++;
    HAL_Delay(1000);
}
```

What could be causing this strange wrapping behavior, and how can I fix it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: how else I am going to display what issue i am facing?

Comment: Select the text in your terminal program, copy it and paste it as text. To retain the formatting, use the `{}` button, press Ctrl+K, or enclose it in triple backslahes - same as for code.

Answer (score 3):

Your terminal - like most terminals - interprets `\n` and `\r` like an old type writer:

- `\n` moves the roller by one line
- `\r` moves the carriage to the left of the paper

The output shows that only the roller was moved but the carriage did not return to the left most position.

Two options:

- Output `\r\n` instead of just `\n`
- Configure your terminal such that `\n` is sufficient to move to the next line **and** return to the left most position.